# Where did GNU sharutils go?

Tags: command-line, homebrew, package-management

I have GNU sharutils installed on my system as `/usr/local/bin/shar`. It's been on my filesystem since 2016, so it isn't something I added recently. However, even after grepping the Homebrew Git repository, I can't seem to find what package it came from. Here is the actual version, which is not symlinked or hard-linked anywhere on the system:

```bsh
$ shar --version
shar (GNU sharutils) 4.10
```

Does Homebrew still provide GNU sharutils in some package that I simply can't find with `brew search` or by grepping the Git history from Homebrew? While I suppose it's possible that I installed it some other way, I tend to rely on Homebrew unless I'm using GNU stow or similar, so I'd expect to see the file linked *somewhere* if it wasn't installed by some other package.

What Homebrew package(s), if any, currently provide shar and unshar? Bonus if you happen to know what happened to uuencode and uudecode as well, as they also report themselves as part of GNU sharutils 4.10.

Comment: In **Terminal**,  what's the _output_ of: `ls -l /usr/local/bin/shar`

Comment: @user3439894 Since it isn't linked elsewhere on the filesystem, this information is unlikely to be useful. However, the result is: `-rwxr-xr-x  1 user  admin  129260 Oct 22  2016 /usr/local/bin/shar`.

Comment: RE: "Since it isn't linked elsewhere on the filesystem, this information is unlikely to be useful." --  Actually it is useful as this probably was not installed by **Homebrew**, because if it was `/usr/local/bin/shar` should be a _symlink_ to `/usr/local/Cellar/.../shar `.  You may have installed it by directly compiling its _source code_ from: [https://www.gnu.org/software/sharutils/](https://www.gnu.org/software/sharutils/)

Comment: macports has a shar package.